# Как перехватить исключения метода

Tags: java

Есть метод в коде. Он подключается к базе и заносит туда значения.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException{

    List<Long> lst = new ArrayList<Long>();

    while(true){

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

            Connection connection = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String SQL;

            Savepoint savepointOne = connection.setSavepoint("SavepointOne");

            try { 
            for (int i = lst.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                SQL = "INSERT INTO logg VALUES (default, '"+lst.get(i)+"')";
                statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
                connection.commit();
                lst.remove(new Integer(i));
            }

            SQL = "INSERT INTO logg VALUES (default, '"+timestamp+"')";
            statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
            connection.commit();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            // Проблема с соединением
            lst.add(timestamp);
            System.out.println("troubles with connection");
            connection.rollback(savepointOne);
        }

        statement.close();
        connection.close();       
        System.out.println("Sleep 2 sec...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

    }
```

Как перехватить эти события непосредственно в методе? Когда пропадает соединение к БД у меня система падает, и я не знаю почему она падает. Точнее не знаю на каком событии

Comment: первое, что приходит в голову - логи. просто разделить код по кускам и пусть пишет разные логи. какого лога не будет - там проблема.

Answer (score 0):

У вас все исключения пробрасываются вверх по стеку к main, поэтому программа завершает своё действие с ошибкой.

**throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException**

Вам нужно **удалить** эту строчку, и выразить блоки **try catch там, где потребует IDE.**

Так же, дополнительно, в потенциально опасных местах вы можете выразить свои блоки.**try{Ваш код} catch(Exception e){Ваше действие}**

По вашему коду

`Connection connection = null;
 Statement statement = null;`

Попробуйте вынести эти переменные в поля класса, или объявить их выше цикла.